# How to use .top() method in a crossfilter group with nested values

Tags: javascript, highcharts, dc.js, crossfilter

**I am using a group of crossfilter.**

When the values in a crossfilter group are like this:

```
{ key:"A", value: 2 }
{ key:"B", value: 5 }
{ key:"C", value: 1 }
```

Then `group.top(2)` returns the top 2 key value pairs based on the **value** i.e., `({key:"B", value: 5}`, `{key:"A", value: 2}` )

But when the group is like this:

```
{ key: "A", value: {count:2} }
{ key: "B", value: {count:5} }
{ key: "C", value: {count:1} }
```

Then `group.top(2)` returns the top 2 key value pair based on **key** (`{key: "A", value: {count:2}}`, `{key: "B", value: {count:5}}`)

#### I have group like this:

```
{ key: "A", value: {count:2} }
{ key: "B", value: {count:5} }
{ key: "C", value: {count:1} }
```

And I want the top 2 key value pairs to be returned on the basis of value's count. The output should be like this:

```
{ key: "B", value: {count:5} }
{ key: "A", value: {count:2} }
```

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[group.order()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order)

> Specifies the order value for computing the top-K groups. The default order is the identity function, which assumes that the reduction values are naturally-ordered (such as simple counts or sums).

```
group.order(v => v.count)
```

Comment: It is a setter, so I’d suggest putting it where you create and initialize the crossfilter group.

Comment: Please don’t ask duplicate questions. What is wrong with setting the order when you create the group? Does it not work?

Comment: In that post, I have written the whole code where I have built the group. Please tell me how to use the order function in that particular code, I am really stuck at it. I have to ask duplicate questions in different way because I am not able to solve it. Please help.

Comment: Hey Gordan. Sorry for troubling you. Its done. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Ok great. Please delete the duplicate question.